# on Element Click get Its Details like html id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular js. Please help me.

my html code is like

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items" class="spanClass" ng-click="spanClicked($event)">{{item}}
</span>
```

and my cotroller code is

```
mymodule.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
$scope.items = ["saurabh", "ram", "Punit", "andhul", "shroraj", "toni"];
$scope.spanClicked = function (event) {
 //Here I want a details of my span element completely like its html, its id and other //element.
           }});
```

Can I use 'this' intead of $event . If yes then please let me know how can I achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: in the controller i want the span tag completely. means span id and its inner html.how can i get these details as I am having event in controller.

Comment: But why do you need that? What's your end goal? It's not very Angular-y to pass an entire HTML element to the controller

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. yes i Know  actually I will add $http dependency in controller and find the span innertext in controller and call on server for the further communication..

Comment: am gessing you are trying to build a wysiwyg or something like that so you can save the inner html in the server, for this i would recomend using a directive. that way you have all the elements right at in your reach thourh element and attrs variables

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dayan for your valueable feed back. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target` to get the element that triggered the event. Then you can use `angular.element(event.target).attr('id')` to get the id and other info.